# Implicite addressing of inner matrix nodes doesn't work here

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, tikz-matrix

Addressing the nodes inside of this matrix implicite doesn't work here. I don't want to name them explicte.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw] (a) {Node};

    \matrix (m) [right=of a,every node/.append style=draw]
    {
        \node {One}; \\
        \node {Two}; \\
    };
    \draw (m-1-1) -- ();
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add `matrix of nodes` option to a matrix the contents are automatically put inside nodes. Only then you can use the `(m-1-1)` syntax.

So the correct code can be

```
\matrix (m) [right=of a,matrix of nodes,nodes={draw}]
{
    One \\
    Two \\
};
```

Note also that every node won't work here as intented. Use `nodes` key

Comment: Ah, thanks. Sidequestion: How can I realize nodes like that inside such a `matrix of nodes`: `\node [align=left] {One\\Two}; \\` ?

Comment: @buhtz you can use pipes for inserting options `|[align=left]| {One\\Two}`. Note the extra brackets for hiding the double backslashes from the parser.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement percusse's answer. If no `matrix of nodes` is used, it's still possible to assign a name to every needed node.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw] (a) {Node};

    \matrix (m) [right=of a, every node/.append style={draw}]
    {
        \node (m-1-1) {One}; \\
        \node {Two}; \\
    };
    \draw (m-1-1) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]